# Scrapy ImportError

Tags: python, twisted, scrapy, importerror

When I try to run Scrapy I get an ImportError stating that `Twisted requires zope.interface 3.6.0 or later`. The version of zope.interface I have is 4.0.5, so I'm perplexed by this error. I've read other suggestions recommending installing zope.interface via pip, but that did not work. I'd like some help figuring out how Twisted or Scrapy is getting the zope.interface version number, or if there's a work-around that I can employ to get this to work?

Answer (score 2):

Verify that you have zope.interface 4.0.5 installed on the same version of Python as you are using to run scrapy.  Most likely you have more than one version of Python installed and scrapy is using a different version than you expect.

Comment: I'm running Python 2.7.3, I also have IronPython 2.7 (which is what I'm testing, in Visual Studio), I've added the packages to both site-packages directories, tried to add Search Paths both through the IDE and manually via sys.path.append, it's still giving the same ImportError. Is there any way I can see what version of zope.interface it's getting or even WHERE it's looking for it?

Comment: You can try `import pprint, sys; pprint.pprint(sys.path)` for starters.

Comment: Interesting, from the output it looks like the items on the path are all under IronPython 2.7, how can I use this info to help? Also I noticed that there are some duplicates, does this even matter?

Comment: Duplicates entries are fine.  Twisted doesn't support IronPython, though, so you need to make sure you are running CPython or PyPy.  CPython won't be compatible with IronPython libraries either, though.  Are you saying you're running the CPython interpreter but seeing an IronPython `sys.path`?  That indicates something in your environment is misconfigured.